# using awk inside of .sh bash script file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, ls

trying to achieve something in linux bash, and failing :(

I have this ls command that I use to get a nice output of cvs file in directory. I also use awk command to get rid of the permissions info which I do not need

```
ls -lrth *.csv | awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}'
```

But now I wish to run this inside of the .sh script file.
In the script if I write something like that, it works

```
LIST=$(ls -lrth *.csv)
echo $LIST
```

but if I add awk to it it doesn't, I'm gessing because of the parametres.

```
LIST=$(ls -lrth *.csv | awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}')
echo $LIST
```

How to correctly write this inside executable sh file?

Comment: @usr - by failing i mean there are no error messages but there is no output either, nothing is being listed.

Comment: @anubhava - it says above, I'm trying to remove the file permission information from the generated by ls command

Comment: a) Dont parse the output of ls, b) always quote your shell variables, c) don't give non-exported variables all upper case names. d) There is no reason for what you have shown us so far to behave differently with/without the awk so the problem lies in some piece of code you haven't shown us so far.

Comment: solved it, I just run the ls command without assigning it to variable, and it worked

Comment: I suspect your problem was that you weren't quoting `$LIST` when you echoed it (i.e. you should have been using `echo "$LIST"`, not `echo $LIST`) and you were just throwing us a red herring when you said that `LIST=$(ls -lrth *.csv); echo $LIST` did what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to run from inside a bash script you can remove the echo:

```
#! /bin/bash
# list_csv.sh
ls -lrth *.csv | awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}'
```

I would suggest, however, you use an alias instead since you are simply trying to replace two commands with one. You can place it in your .bash_aliases file to persist between sessions, or run it from the console to use it for one session:

```
 alias lscsv="ls -lrth *.csv | awk '{print \$5, \$6, \$7, \$8, \$9}'"
```